# Issues linking Boost.python example

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to compile [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html) example but getting errors about `undefined reference to PyInt_Type/PyString_FromString/PyNumber_Divide` etc. I have already linked my build against `boost_python` and `python3.6m`.

I'm building it with
`g++ example.cpp  -L/usr/include/boost/python -lboost_python -lpython3.6m  -I/usr/include/python3.6m`

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/exec.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Python.h>

using namespace boost::python;

int main() {

  Py_Initialize();
  object main_module = import("__main__");
  object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

  object ignored = exec("hello = file('hello.txt', 'w')\n"
                        "hello.write('Hello world!')\n"
                        "hello.close()",
                        main_namespace);
}
```

**Note** :

1. I have python3.6-dev installed
2. I was able to run [this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) using the same build parameters and include directives
3. Full [list](https://pastebin.com/tjbyK9t8) of errors
4. I'm using  Ubuntu 16.04

**Also**: If i understand correctly following thing happening: When i'm linking my build with lboost_python it uses some functions `PyInt_Type`, `PyString_FromString`. It has information about their return types and input parameters, but not their real definitions i.e. function body, that is defined in some other library (In my case it is python library) and i have to tell linker about this library to be include it in build. Is my understanding correct ? If yes then why linking against `python3.6m` didn't help ?

Comment: What if you remove Qt completely, does it work then?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No, it doesn't. I compiled it with `g++ example.cpp -L/usr/include -lpython3.6m -L/usr/include/boost/python -lboost_python -I/usr/include/boost/python/ -I/usr/include/python3.6m` and it gave exactly the same errors.

Comment: Well, then edit your question to get it closer to an actually minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost_python` probably points to python 2.7 version, for example in debian stretch (which should have a similar package as in ubuntu 16.04).

```
> cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> ls -l libboost_python*.*
... libboost_python-py35.a
... libboost_python-py27.a
... libboost_python.a -> libboost_python-py27.a
... libboost_python-py27.so.1.55.0
... libboost_python-py27.so -> libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0
... libboost_python.so -> libboost_python-py27.so
... libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0
... libboost_python-py35.so -> libboost_python-py35.so.1.62.0
```

I guess python 3.6 version of that library is probably not readily available. The easiest option may be to use python 3.5 if `libboost_python-py35` is not compatible with python 3.6, i.e.

```
-lboost_python-py35
```

for dynamic linking.

Comment: `g++ example.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llibboost_python-py35.a -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m  -I/usr/include/python3.5m` i tried to build with this but its says that it cannot find -llibboost_python-py35.a, even though i have this in my /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder.

Comment: @Kamanji it should be `-lboost_python-py35` (or maybe `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py35.a` in case of static linking)

Answer (score 0):

You're linking the libraries in the wrong order.  `boost_python` must come first, and `python3.6m` must come after it, because `boost_python` depends on `python3.6m`.

P.S.: This is wrong: `-L/usr/include`: `-L` tells the linker where to find libraries, but `/usr/include` contains headers, not libraries.  You should not need it at all, but if you do, it is `-L/usr/lib` or similar.

Comment: I tried to build using ` g++ example.cpp  -L/usr/include/boost/python -lboost_python -lpython3.6m  -I/usr/include/python3.6m `, but got the same errors.

Comment: @Kamanji: `-L/usr/include/boost/python` makes no sense and neither does `-I/usr/include/python3.6m`.  The first claims to specify a library path but is a header path; the second claims to specify a header path but contains part of a library name.